# getStoreCategories() returns nothing

Tags: magento

I'm currently learning Magento and seem to have come across a problem that is familiar with a lot of people in my position, yet none of the given solutions work for me. I am looking to populate the navigation menu with all the categories found in the root category but the piece of code I have to do this does not work. Here is the excerpt of code taken which should perform such a task:

```
<div id="utilities">
    <?php $_menu = ''?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php $_menu .= $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php if ($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">

        <ul id="nav">

            <?php $_anyActive = false; foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); } ?>
             <li class="home <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li> 

            <?php echo $_menu; ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Now, I've troubleshooted this quite extensively, and started by doing a var_dump() on the $this-?getStoreCategories() but this returned a NULL. I know that the statement does not get any further than that method so can conclude that the error lies in this line of code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
```

I have tried creating new root categories and populating these with subcategories (also filling with products) then changing the root category in the admin settings to this newly created one, still to no avail. I know this code is being pulled into the page as if I type static text before the offending statement it prints to the screen.

I'm flabbergasted to say the least. Any help would be so much appreciated, and thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I faced similar issue on Enterprise edition with varnish. It worked for me after clearing the var/cache and var/full_page_cache directories

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a Block, that has no `getStoreCategories()` method. `$this` - is a reference to your manually created block.

Magento has high level of abstraction so every problem here can be solved in different ways.

**Use:**

```
Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()
```

**Instead of:**

```
$this->getStoreCategories()
```

When it works - better create `getStoreCategories()` in your block and move this code to it - as supposed by Magento architecture.

Comment: OK, I understand this. Thanks for your reply, but I'm now getting an error. I believe the drawItem is the problem. In its documentation it says deprecated after 1.4, and I am using 1.4.1.1. Is there an alternate method I should be using? Thank you so much for your response. I feel I need to go back a bit and study blocks as I'm a bit confused with your last sentence!

Comment: The solution heavily depends on error you get - your questions lack information: error description, your block class description (name and ancestor), layout structure for this block. I think you're trying to copy-paste functionality from some phtml (e.g. 'catalog/navigation/top.phtml') - it's against Magento architecture, because every phtml has its own block and class ($this is different for every phtml). In this case you need to get full understanding of 'layout/block/phtml' system Magento uses. Without it it's hard to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to get a menu of categories is with the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml()`.

So for any block that is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` or descends from it can use the template `app/code/design/base/default/template/navigation/top.phtml` which calls that method.

Comment: And how one is supposed to customize html for this thing or exclude some categories for example?